# Twilio callback Error using serverless Whatsapp using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-twiml

I am following a tutorial by Brent Schooley of Twilio who [showed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eqtQ76X_owQ&list=PLqrz4nXepkz4ELSEyNrh3kP3vbq-SriK4&ab_channel=Twilio) how to create a serverless Whatsapp service using NodeJS that queries a value from Google Sheets [(his source code)](https://gist.github.com/brentschooley/33895752c207b1e44b15b429c86daa5a). My dependencies seem correct, and the deployment happens correctly my sandbox is configured correctly with the generated webhook but I'm getting a callback error and it says I need to put it in the right place (error 82002). I'm using this as a project and new to NodeJS after following their single message tutorials. Here is my code:

```
const { GoogleSpreadsheet} = require('google-spreadsheet');

let fs = require('fs');
const { Twilio } = require('twilio');
const { error } = require('console');
const Response = require('twilio/lib/http/response');
let credsFile = Runtime.getAssets()['/creds.json'].path;
let creds = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(credsFile, 'utf-8'));

async function getName(name) {
    const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('where I enter the Google Sheet ID');
    await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(creds);
    await doc.loadInfo();

    const krishnaNamesSheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];

    const krishaNames = await krishnaNamesSheet.getRows();

    const krishna = krishaNames.find(row => row.Name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase());

    return krishna;

}

exports.handler = async function(context, event, callback) {
    const twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    const name = event.Body.trim();
    console.log(name);

    const krishna = await getName(name);

    if(krishna) {
        twiml.message(`The meaning of the Krishna name ${event.Body} is: ${krishna.Meaning}`);
    } else {
        twiml.message(`I'm sorry, I don't know about that name yet!`);
    
    }

    callback(null, twiml);
};
```

What's wrong with this? I looked at other examples like this:

```
if(krishna) {
        return callback(null, twiml.message(`The meaning of the Krishna name ${event.Body} is: ${krishna.Meaning}`));
    } else {
        return callback(new Error(return twiml.message(`I'm sorry, I don't know about that name yet!`));
    
    }
};
```

But didn't work. What is the right way to prevent this error. Here is error response:

> Error - 82002 Error on Twilio Function response Your Function
> invocation resulted in StatusCode 5xx. Possible Causes Your Function
> timed out before responding Your Function returned an error response
> Possible Solutions Your Function must contain a callback. Make sure
> you place the Function callback callback(err, response) is placed
> correctly in your Function code. If you are using a JavaScript
> promise, make sure the callback is called in both success and catch
> blocks. Your Function responded with an error.

Raw error response body:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection:
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessagingResponse' of undefined
> at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/handlers/ZNd211e21df8b5046306e730661731dc38.js:26:36)
> at Object.exports.handler (/var/task/node_modules/runtime-handler/index.js:339:10)
> at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/runtime-handler.js:17:17)
> at Runtime.handleOnceNonStreaming (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:73:25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is the way you require `Twilio`. You have:

```js
const { Twilio } = require('twilio');
```

But it should just be:

```js
const Twilio = require('twilio');
```

Comment: I don't have the credits to vote, but this worked! Thank you very much @philnash!

Comment: You should be able to mark a question as correct (the tick)? Either way, glad that sorted you out!

Comment: When I tried clicking the upward facing carrot, there was a blue notification that said I need 15 credits to cast a vote but my feedback was recorded, haha. 4 more points and I'll come back here!

Comment: Ah, sure, but beneath the up and down arrows there should be [a tick that you can click to accept the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGwTL.png). I think you can accept answers on your questions regardless of your current reputation.

Comment: Sorry, marked it as accepted answer using the tick!